# Receive push notification with APP closed (iOS)

Tags: push-notification, xamarin.ios, xamarin.forms, apple-push-notifications

Hello fellow Xamarin developers,

We are developing an APP that should receive push notification, even with APP closed.

I am receiving notifications when the APP is open or in the background, but after restarting the device the notifications are not received.

Note:

I read the content of the page https://developer.apple.com/reference/uikit/uiapplicationdelegate

I added in Info.plist: UIBackgroundModes / remote-notification

Overwrote the methods: RegisteredForRemoteNotifications, ReceivedRemoteNotification and DidReceiveRemoteNotification

Any tips? Can I actually receive notifications after rebooting the device? I would need to create some service to register the device (In Android was necessary to create the service, in Windows-UWP No)?

Thank you very much!

Comment: You shouldn't have to do anything special to make notifications work after a reboot

Answer (score 0):

I following this tutorial and it's working for me perfect

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/notification-hubs/xamarin-notification-hubs-ios-push-notification-apns-get-started

Comment: Hello Mich, I used exactly this tutorial. After opening the application it works perfectly even if I close it. However, after restarting the device, the application does not receive the notifications.

Comment: Use release (maybe this is debug problem) version and try it again please.

Comment: In android you use <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED" /> or your app working without this ?

Comment: Dear G. Mich,
The push notication on Android and Windows is working fine, we even use the permission you mentioned on Android.
I'll take the test you indicated on iOS with release.
Thanks for the support !!!

Comment: Hi @RigelAguilar I am also facing the same issue.When i restart the app the notifications is not working for ios.it is working good in  android.Did you solve your problem?

Comment: Hi @PraveenBaruri, I refined every part that involves notification of sending non-IOS and started working, not being able to notice anything different from the old version to a new, but worked.